# Update Table using Computation from 2 other Tables

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

Good Morning.
I want to ask some question but before that I want to explain what I'm currently have before asking the question.

I have 3 Tables and they are.

`Table: Receiving`

[image]

`Table: GeneralInventory`

[image]

and last one is `Table: item_master_list`

[image]

I have a program in VB.Net that will do the ff.

1.Based on `Table: Receiving` i will select an `RINo` and I will use the example on the image above(`RI00000001`)

2.After Selecting the `RI00000001` in `Table: Receiving` i will press the button 
`POST` and after that this is what my code does.

-The code will check if the Data from the Column `ItemCode` of `Table:Receiving` has the same Data in the Column `ItemCode` of `Table: GeneralInventory`.

-Now if the Comparison is True or there's a same Data from both Tables the Column `QtyPack` and `QtyStan` from `Table: Receiving` will be added/SUM in the Column `Qty` of `GeneralInventory`

-Now if the Comparison is False or theres no comparison between two tables then the data will be inserted in `GeneralInventory`.

I hope you get it but if not here is the sample image.

[image]

and now my code for that procedure is this.

Code for finding.

```
Select * 
From 
    GeneralInventory GI 
Inner Join 
    Receiving RE on GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode 
Where RE.RINo = 'MyValue'
```

Now if the code above is true then this is the code for Updating

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN receiving RE ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND
GI.Qty = RE.QtyPack
SET GI.Qty = CAST(GI.Qty + RE.QtyPack + RE.QtyStan AS DECIMAL(6,2)) 
Where RE.RINo =  'MyValue'
```

or if it is false then this is the code for inserting.

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory(ItemCode, Qty) 
SELECT RE.ItemCode, RE.QtyPack 
FROM 
    Receiving RE LEFT JOIN 
    GeneralInventory GI ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND 
        GI.Qty =CAST(RE.QtyPack + Re.QtyStan AS DECIMAL(6,2)) 
WHERE RE.RINo  = 'MyValue'
```

Now here is my Question and My Question is related to the `Item_Master_List` and here it is.

How can I achieve something like this? First before I will update the `Table:GeneralInventory` using the `Table: Receiving` I want to do some computation in `Table: item_master_list` what i mean is before i update or insert the data in `generalinventory` i will multiply it in `item_masterlist`.

Like find the same value in `item_master_list` then multiply it using the column of `QtyperUoM` using the value in `receiving` before saving it in `generalinventory`

I hope you get it.

TYSM

Comment: Is there any condition to do the multiplication from another table?

Comment: Refer this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @AT-2016 I think there's no condition with that it is like multiplying the QtyPack * QtyperUoM

Comment: Just need to ask, you mean you want to update and insert into table? What do you mean "if the code above is true" then update and " if it is false then this is the code for inserting" what value for true and what value if false;

Comment: Please add one tag "VB.Net" in your question

Comment: Noted Sir @eronax59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE generalinventory gi
set gi.qty = (SELECT (r.QtyPack * r.QtyperUoM + r.QtySan) 
           from receiving r, item_master_list ml
           where r.itemCode = ml.itemCode
           and   t.itemCode = gi.itemCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query to do the update:

```
UPDATE GeneralInventory SET Qty = (Qty * QtyperUoM) + l.QtyStan
FROM GeneralInventory s INNER JOIN item_master_list i 
on s.ItemCode = i.ItemCode INNER JOIN Receiving l ON s.ItemCode = l.ItemCode
```

Just did an INNER JOIN regarding the table relationship.

Comment: It has an error Sir and my question is how can I add the `QtyStan`? I mean `QtyPack` * `QtyperUoM` + `QtyStan`

Comment: Edited the post. Just did the same thing - INNER JOIN. As you have item code as FK, it can be done maintaining the relation between the tables.

Comment: The word `from` has a curly underline

Comment: and i change QtySpan to QtyStan